# Spectral norm of modified matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

Let $K$ be a symmetric, positive definite matrix and $S$ be a diagonal matrix such that all entries on its diagonal are greater than $1$. I am trying to prove the following relation.

$$ \| S K S - K \| \leq \|K\| \left( \| S \|^2 - 1 \right),$$

where $\| \cdot \|$ denotes the spectral norm of a matrix.

I feel that intuitively the relation should hold but I haven't been able to prove it. Any hints or solutions (or even a counterexample) would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As a general statement without your constraints on $S$, this is clearly false. This is clearly false. For counterexample, take
$$
K = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}, \quad S = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}.
$$

Comment: Certainly, it wouldn't hold for any matrix $S$. I was just curious for the specific case where $S$ is a diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true. Since $S\succeq I$, we have $\|S-I\|=\|S\|-1$. Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|SKS-K\|
&\le\|SKS-KS\|+\|KS-K\|\\
&\le\|S-I\|\|K\|\|S\|+\|K\|\|S-I\|\\
&=(\|S\|-1)\|K\|\|S\|+\|K\|(\|S\|-1)\\
&=\|K\|(\|S\|^2-1).
\end{aligned}
$$
Note that $K$ doesn't need to be positive definite. It can be a general square matrix. $S$ also doesn't need to be a diagonal matrix. As long as $S\succeq I$, the proof above remains valid.

Comment: Oh that was simple! Thanks!